# amazon-linux-extras command not found

Tags: linux, command-line

I tried to install `sudo yum install -y amazon-linux-extras`, but getting below error:

> No match for argument: amazon-linux-extras
> Error: Unable to find a match: amazon-linux-extras

please suggest me what i can do in this case. also when i check with command:

```bash
which amazon-linux-extras
/usr/bin/which: no amazon-linux-extras in (/root/.local/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin)
```

I am getting above error.

Comment: Which Linux distribution? Amazon Linux 1/2?

Comment: Amazon Linux 2023

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Amazon Linux 2023 FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/linux/amazon-linux-2023/faqs/) :

> **Q:** Does AL2023 have Amazon-Linux-Extras like AL2?
>
> **A:** No, AL2023 does not have extras. For higher-level software packages like language runtimes, we will use the quarterly release
> where we will add major/minor updates to packages as separate
> namespaced packages in addition to the default package provided in the
> repository. For example, default Python version in Amazon Linux 2023
> may be 3.8, but we will add Python 3.9 (python39) as a separate
> namespaced package whenever it is made available. These additional
> packages will closely follow their upstream release cadence and
> support model and their support policies can be accessed by the
> package manager for compliance and security use cases. Default
> packages will continue to be supported throughout the life of AL2023.

This explains your problem - `amazon-linux-extras` doesn't exist in
Amazon Linux 2023, although it existed in Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: Thanks Sir. You are helpful and kind person in this world. 

Comment: Thanks, you're welcome.